# Zend File Validator return wrong message

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation

below code return "File '' is not readable or does not exist" always:

```
$filters = array(
    '*' => 'stringTrim'
);
$validators = array(
    'image'=> array(
        'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
        new Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize(array('minheight'=>0,'minwidth'=>0,'maxheight'=>1024,'maxwidth'=>1024)),
    )
);
$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators);
$input->setData(array_merge($data, $_FILES));
if (!$input->isValid()) {
    $this->_errors = $input->getMessages();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input name of your file input has to be `image`. Also, be sure your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. The format of `$_FILES` is explained [here](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php).

Aside from that I don't detect any code in `Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize` that can operate on `$_FILES`. I think you've got to pass the actual path to the file, e.g. `'image' => $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` (in your `$input->setData()` call).

Comment: tnx, worked. $files['image'] = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; and use $files insteade $_FILES

Comment: now it return Maximum allowed width for image '' should be '94' but '128' detected. it should be Maximum allowed width for image 'image' should be '94' but '128' detected

Comment: Not sure about that one, might be a bug. If so, do report it to the ZF dev team.